# How to install kvm in Debian (Lenny) over powerpc

Tags: debian, software-installation, kvm, powerpc

I am emulating powerpc using qemu-system-ppc on top of x86, and running debian-lenny-ppc with it. I want to install kvm inside that debian. I have learned that the kvm and qemu-kvm packages are [not available](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=kvm) for the powerpc architecture.

I have found two packages (kvm-source and [Edit1]qemu) and installed it, but I don't know how to proceed with it further. How do I install kvm on powerpc? Do I need to cross-compile it as well, as given on http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/PowerPC_Host_Userspace?

[Edit1]:
Approach1: I downloaded qemu-kvm source code (http://sourceforge.net/projects/kvm/files/qemu-kvm/0.13.0/qemu-kvm-0.13.0.tar.gz/download) , configured

```
#./configure --target-list="ppc-softmmu" 
#make
```

But I am getting this error:

```
CC    ppc-softmmu/virtio-pci.o
~/qemu-kvm-0.13.0/hw/virtio-pci.c: In function 'virtio_pci_mask_notifier':
~/qemu-kvm-0.13.0/hw/virtio-pci.c:436: error: invalid use of undefined 
type 'struct kvm_irq_routing_entry'
~/qemu-kvm-0.13.0/hw/virtio-pci.c:436: error: dereferencing pointer to 
incomplete type
```

Comment: Kvm on ppc is still experimental. I think you'll be better off getting it from [upstream](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/PowerPC).

Comment: Holy crap, I had no idea Kvm was coming to powerpc! This gives our old G5 a whole new use!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gilles suggested, why dont you try the details in the [PowerPC_KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/PowerPC_Host_Userspace) link.
They have described the whole procedure there.

---

Added a Document on
 [KVM on PowerPC](http://alex.csgraf.de/clt/2010/PowerPC%20KVM.pdf) .

Thanks,
Sen

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I've already tried that approach and I am pasting the error in the question description.

Comment: Why dont you just try giving "--with-patched-kernel" while configuring..

Comment: I believe the options you gave while configuring is minimal..

Comment: I tried qemu-kvm-0.11, and got it installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully installed openSUSE 11.1 PPC on my PowerPC P5 9131-52A and compiled qemu 1.1.1 . You must have zlib and glib-2.2.4 before compiling. Then:

```
#./configure --target-list="ppc-softmmu ppc64_softmmu"
# make 
# make install
```

Be aware that after installing qemu you must uninstall glib-2.2.4 by doing make uninstall in the directory of  glib-2.2.4 because otherwise some apps might break.

Then you can `qemu-system-ppc -vnc :0 -hda DEBIAN.img -cdrom DEBIAN.iso -boot d`
and connect to :0 using a VNC client. But do note that it is very slow.